# How to pickle python class wrapping TensorFlow graph?

Tags: python, serialization, tensorflow, pickle

I use pythontex to make dynamic reproducible reports. I have a class wrapping tensorflow graph.

In my document I create my class and, therein, construct tensorflow graph.

Importing tensorflow module and constructing graph is a long process so I want to pickle the result not to rerun this process every time.

But I fail with error. `can't pickle class tensorflow.python.util.xxx`. I suppose it's a known problem. How can I customize my class to dump and load it conveniently? Or maybe I could pickle python session or tensorflow session?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tf.train.Saver`. Someone wrote a helpful post about this [here](https://kevincodeidea.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/tensorflow-save-and-load-a-model-in-a-serious-way-from-different-files/). You can only pickle classes defined at the top level of a module (`tensorflow.xxx` would be fine but `tensorflow.python.util.xxx` isn't), so you won't be able to pickle the graph (for details on what you can pickle, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)). The most likely solution is to find another way to save it to a file.

Comment: Why cannot one pickle a list? One *can* do this.